# PHP Multiple Logins project (facebook/twitter/Google)

Tags: library, php, facebook, social-networks

What I am looking for is a library that will help me manage social logins.

I was hoping one of you know about a such tool or git project.

I know where to find the individual APIs. It would be great to know if a there is one with (facebook/twitter/Google) merged into one project.

Preferably in PHP, with easy documentation.

Comment: Might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401026/is-there-an-omniauth-for-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use OpenID.

At the server side, you can use one of these libraries: http://openid.net/developers/libraries/

At the client side, you can use [OpenID selector](https://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/): [demo](http://openid-selector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo.html)

---

If you want a custom solution, you might need to develop it by your own. The documentation for authentification methods of the big providers is pretty good:

- [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login)
- [Twitter Authentication & Authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth)
- [Google OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?hl=de)

Comment: Hi moose do you know if I can create a user in my table from that authentication? is that possible?

Comment: Just for clarification: You have a database. This database has a table for users and you want to generate an entry in that table after authentification? Yes, thats possible. In fact, the autentification would be pretty useless if you didn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

All of the mainstream social networks (Facebook, Twitter, Google Plus, etc..) use either OAuth1 or OAuth 2 for authenatication and consumption of some of their APIs.

So you might want to take a look into an OAuth library, like the one below:

https://packagist.org/packages/lusitanian/oauth

If you're using composer or PSR-0 autoloading, then the integration should be pretty straight forward.

You can also browser composer's library to look for more packages that fit your purposes:
https://packagist.org/search/?q=oauth

Answer (score 0):

[PHP OAuth Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html) is really great and I'm using it for the past 6 months. It supports various OAuth providers like Google, Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo etc...

From [phpclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/) :

> This class can authorize the access of users to an API using the OAuth
>   protocol.
>
> It abstracts OAuth 1.0, 1.0a and 2.0 in the same class, so you can use
>   the same obtain a token to authorize the access on behalf of the
>   current user any API that supports any version of the OAuth protocol.
>
> It provides built-in support to several popular OAuth servers, so you
>   do not have to configure the class manually with all OAuth server
>   specific details.
>
> Currently it provides built-in support for OAuth servers of 37Signals,
>   Amazon, Bitbucket, Box.net, Buffer, Discogs, Disqus, Dropbox with
>   OAuth 1.0 and 2.0, Etsy, Eventful, Facebook, Fitbit, Flickr,
>   Foursquare, github, Google with OAuth 1.0a and OAuth 2.0, Instagram,
>   LinkedIn, Microsoft, Rdio, Reddit, RightSignature, Salesforce,
>   Scoop.it, StockTwits, SurveyMonkey, Tumblr, Twitter, VK, Withings,
>   Xero, XING and Yahoo.
>
> Every other OAuth server is supported setting end point URLs and other
>   parameters using specific class variables. Additional servers may be
>   supported without changing the main class by configuring a separate
>   JSON configuration file.
>
> The class can also send requests to API using the previously obtained
>   OAuth access token.
>
> It also supports 2 legged API access, so it can send signed API
>   requests that do not require user authorization.
>
> For servers that support offline access like Google and Box.net, the
>   class can also verify if the access token expired and refresh the
>   token value before sending an API call, without requiring the user
>   presence.